# Laravel eager loading, select only those which have related models

Tags: laravel

Projects and users are Many-to-many related, how can I select only projects that have related users? Do I have to use join? 
Something like:

```
$projects = Project::with('users')->having('count(users)','>',0)->get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Project::with('users')->has('users')->get();
```